# How do i display CoreData data from the past week or month?

Tags: swift, date, core-data, swiftui, nspredicate

I have data saved as meals; Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner and Snacks. I am trying to return a total for the calories from all meals for each day over the previous week.

The meal data is saved as below with .date :

```
func saveBreakfast() {
             
         
    let newBreakfastItem = BreakfastItem(context: self.moc)
    newBreakfastItem.id = UUID()
    newBreakfastItem.name = self.item.name
    newBreakfastItem.calories = Int32(self.totalCalories)
    newBreakfastItem.carbs = Int32(self.totalCarbs)
    newBreakfastItem.protein = Int32(self.totalProtein)
    newBreakfastItem.fat = Int32(self.totalFats)
    newBreakfastItem.date = self.dateAdded




    do {
        if self.mocB.hasChanges { // saves only if changes are made
            try? self.mocB.save()
     
        }
     
    }
 }



func saveLunch() {
  

    let newLunchItem = LunchItem(context: self.moc)
    newLunchItem.id = UUID()
    newLunchItem.name = self.item.name
    newLunchItem.calories = Int32(self.caloriesPerServing)
    newLunchItem.carbs = Int32(self.carbsPerServing)
    newLunchItem.protein = Int32(self.proteinPerServing)
    newLunchItem.fat = Int32(self.fatsPerServing)
    newLunchItem.date = self.dateAdded

    do {
        if self.mocL.hasChanges {
            try? self.mocL.save()
        }
    }
}
```

I am currently working with the below function to try and get it working for a single day (Date() - 1 day, so yesterday)

```
func dayOneCal(at date: Date) -> NSNumber {

    
    let request1:NSFetchRequest<BreakfastItem> = BreakfastItem.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<BreakfastItem>
    let request2:NSFetchRequest<LunchItem> = LunchItem.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<LunchItem>
    let request3:NSFetchRequest<DinnerItem> = DinnerItem.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<DinnerItem>
    let request4:NSFetchRequest<SnackItem> = SnackItem.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<SnackItem>


    let startDate = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: date)
    var components = DateComponents()
    components.day = -1
    components.second = -1
    let endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: startDate)!

    request1.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@ AND date <= %@", startDate as NSDate, endDate as NSDate)

    request2.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@ AND date <= %@", startDate as NSDate, endDate as NSDate)

    request3.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@ AND date <= %@", startDate as NSDate, endDate as NSDate)

    request4.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@ AND date <= %@", startDate as NSDate, endDate as NSDate)



    let totalDailyBreakfastCals = BreakfastItems.map({$0.calories}).reduce(0, +)
    let totalDailyLunchCals = LunchItems.map({$0.calories}).reduce(0, +)
    let totalDailyDinnerCals = DinnerItems.map({$0.calories}).reduce(0, +)
    let totalDailySnacksCals = SnackItems.map({$0.calories}).reduce(0, +)

    let totalDailyCals = totalDailyBreakfastCals + totalDailyLunchCals  + totalDailyDinnerCals + totalDailySnacksCals


    return totalDailyCals as NSNumber



}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: What's working what's not working? It's unclear where you are struggling exactly.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't add -1 to startDate when calculating endDate, not if you want endDate to be after startDate that is ;)

Comment: You've shown code for saving your entities, and you've defined your `NSFetchRequest`s. Are you actually running those requests against the `NSManagedObjectContext`?